# Querying Relationship is very slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a new table based on relationships, after retrieving results.The query works and outputs for few results.

```
match (p:Person)-[r:LIVES]->(t:COUNTRY)<-[r2:LIVES]-(p2:Person)
where p<>p2 and r.year = r2.year and r.year >=2015 and r2.year>=2015
return p,r,t,r2,p2 limit 25;
```

But the server stops responding when I want all results.

```
match (p:Person)-[r:LIVES]->(t:COUNTRY)<-[r2:LIVES]-(p2:Person)
where p<>p2 and r.year = r2.year and r.year >=2015 and r2.year>=2015
return p,r,t,r2,p2;
```

This is basically self-joining relationship "LIVES".I have searched a lot but not found a way to create indices on relationships.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How big is your graph and what would you like to achieve

Comment: Its supposed to have 218364 relations based on the cut-off I want.

Comment: Are you sure it's a server which stops responding? It may be Neo4j browser because it can't plot this big graph.

Comment: Try the same query by adding `PROFILE` in the start, and see what happen

Comment: Yes the browser stops responding and it says connection to the server is stopped.Also I have had to restart the server then.

Comment: I added `PROFILE` and the browser stops responding again.

Comment: Are you running this query in the neo4j browser? Also, your query is not trying to "create relationships", so you should probably change your question's title unless you actually show a query creating relationships.

Comment: You want to use `EXPLAIN` not PROFILE. Profile runs the query (and you already know it can't complete the query). Explain will create a plan, but not run it. So you can see at what point of the plan the query blows up.

Answer (score 1):

Since it sound like you aren't bound to the results format, I would like to offer an alternative Cypher.

The thing is that in your cypher, p and p2 basically form a cartesian product of people in the same year and country. So really you just need to group people by year and country, filter out groups of one, and then every pair in that bag is your p and p2 from your original query.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES]->(t:COUNTRY)
WHERE r.year >=2015
WITH t, DISTINCT r.year as Year, COLLECT({n:p, r:r}) as people
WHERE SIZE(people) > 1
RETURN t, people
```